# Alternar 2 div con jquery, php y actualizar link

Tags: php, jquery

Hola amigos necesito alternar 2 div, que son para cambiar el formato de un video sin recargar la página

EL problema de los div lo resolví así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cambiaVisibilidad() {
   var div1 = document.getElementById('precio1');
   var div2 = document.getElementById('precio2');
   if(div2.style.display == 'block'){
       div2.style.display = 'none';
       div1.style.display = 'block';
   }else{
      div2.style.display = 'block';
      div1.style.display = 'none';
     }
   }
 </script>



 <div class="show" id="precio1">
<div class="video" align="center" >
 <ul>
        <p class="textocomentarios">Transmisión de La Plata - <?php     echo"$AgradLP";?> </p>
        <iframe width="660" height="390" align= "center" src="<?php echo"$LinkLP";?>" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" border="0" >Tu navegador no soporta frames!! actualiza tu Navegador</iframe>
  </ul>
</div>


</div>
 <div style="display:none;" id="precio2">

<div class="video1" align="center" >
  <ul>
        <p class="textocomentarios">Transmisión de La Plata - <?php echo"$AgradLP";?> </p>
        <iframe width="660" height="390" align= "center" src="<?php echo"$LinkLP";?>" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" border="0" >Tu navegador no soporta frames!! actualiza tu Navegador</iframe>
</ul>
</div> 

 </div>
  <div class="btn" align="center" onclick="cambiaVisibilidad()"><a id="accionar">Cambiar Tamaño de la Transmisión</a>     </div>
```

pero el problema que tengo que si el video esta corriendo, al cambiar el tamaño mientras veo el video en el nuevo formato el otro sigue corriendo atrás

Answer (score 0):

Basta con que crees un único iframe, e ir actualizando el contenido del mismo

```css
#video {
  position: relative;
}

#video iframe {
  max-width: 80%;
}

.video {
  background: yellow
}

.video1 {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div id="video" align="center">
   <p class="textocomentarios"> Transmisión de La Plata - <?=$AgradLP?> </p>
   <iframe width="660" height="390" align="center"> Tu navegador no soporta iframes, actualízalo.</iframe>
</div>


<ul id="opciones" style="display:none">
  <li id="precio1" data-src="<?=$LinkLP>" data-class="video">opción 1</li>
  <li id="precio2" data-src="<?=$LinkLP>" data-class="video1">opción 2</li>
</ul>

<div align="center">
<a id="cambiar" href="#" class="btn">Cambiar Tamaño de la Transmisión</a>
</div>

<script>
;(function() {
  var ops = document.getElementById('opciones').children
  var video = document.getElementById('video')
  var btn = document.getElementById('cambiar')
  
  video.dataset.target = ops[0].id
  video.classList.add(ops[0].dataset.class)
  video.querySelector('iframe').src = ops[0].dataset.src
  
  function CambiarOpcion(e)
  {
    var actual = document.getElementById(video.dataset.target)
    var siguiente = actual.nextElementSibling || ops[0]
    
    video.classList.remove(actual.dataset.class)
    video.classList.add(siguiente.dataset.class)
    video.dataset.target = siguiente.id
    video.querySelector('iframe').src = siguiente.dataset.src
    
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', CambiarOpcion)
}())
</script>
```

Comment: Lo estoy probando y no lo puedo hacer funcionar